# How to preprocess more in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I was wondering, and some people with a lot more knowledge than me will probably know the answer :

Why isn't the C (in my case its for C++) preprocessor more complete ?

What I mean is why couldn't we use for example C++ as the preprocessor language ? It would allow us to do so much more about classes, generate dynamic code etc...

Ideally I would want to call a C++ function just like a preprocessor macro, with a concrete example, I would like to do things like:

```
#void generateVariable(std::string type, std::string name) {
#    if (name[0] == 'p')
#        cout << "protected:" << endl << type << " " << name << ";" << endl;
#    if (name[0] == 'm')
#        cout << "public:" << endl << type << " " << name << ";" << endl;
#    std::string prefix = name;
#    prefix.erase(2, npos);
#    name.erase(0,2);
#    name[0] = toupper(name[0]);
#    cout << "public:" << endl << type << "get" << name << "() const { return " << prefix+name << "; }" << endl;
#}
```

So that I could call

```
class A {
    generateVariable(static const int, p_age)
}
```

And it would generate

```
class A {
    protected:
        static const int p_age;
    public:
        static const int getAge() const { return p_age; }
}
```

Are there actually ways to do this kind of thing, whithout parsing the whole file with a scripting language and rewriting it ?

Comment: The _'c++ preprocessor'_ by these meanings is template metaprogramming! What are you bothering about actually?

Comment: Learn about template metaprogramming. It is related to what you want to do.

Comment: Because then it wouldn't be C++, it would be Lisp.

Comment: Oh template metaprogramming is actually exactly what I was looking for. Found a great article on codeproject.com. Thanks!

Comment: Two more reasons why not: 1) because C and C++ aren't actually very good languages for generating code; 2) because it's unnecessary - there's nothing stopping you writing your metaprogram as a separate regular C++ program, and without the symbolic capability of Lisp or whatever, nothing special to gain by rolling them into a single build step.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor actually **can** do this (though I wouldn't recommend to do so):

```
#define generateVariable(__type__, __name__) \
    protected: __type__ __name__; \
    public: __type__ get##__name__() { return __name__; }

class A {
     generateVariable(static const int, p_age);
}
```

`get##__name__()` will expand to `getp_age()` though ...

Comment: yeah I already know that this is possible, but I'd really like to parse strings in the preprocessor. Variables names as in my example to be concrete.

Comment: @hilnius You can still do the other way round, getting something like `Age` as the parameter and generate `getAge()` and `p_Age`.